# Would this question be on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

This is a question I have that pertains to writing, and I was wondering if it would be on topic if so I would migrate it, or ask it on the main site.

## Question

> What types of methods can be used in writing a scientific research paper introduction? I have read articles on a particular topic (COVID-19), and they are peer-reviewed scientific journals. My professor says my introduction should be 3-4 pages. I was thinking if there was a technique because I would reason that the an introduction in an English/Literature based class would be different from a scientific one because I am presenting someone else's data, and constructing topic sentences rest of the paper. The audience of the paper is my professor, and the intent is that we research information about our topic and present it as back up for our thesis. For example just simplifying my thesis I am writing about why Vaccine research takes so long on the contrary to what mainstream media says. For sources I have sources highlighting the structure of SARS, 1 Clinical Trial, and some with different, and specific vaccine approaches being used for SARS-CoV-2. I have never done an introduction for scientific research paper that was 3-4 pages. An approach I had in mind was to go over the sources, and what they had in this order:

1. Background to Problem
2. Structure of Virus
3. How Structure of Virus Impacts Research
4. Research done on both SARS-CoV-1(2003), and SARS-CoV-2(2019)
5. Modified Thesis Paragraph

I was recently reading the questions that would be on topic from the help section. I was wondering if it would fit under General copywriting, style, and organization or under something else?

Answer (score 4):

## On topic but needs focus

This question is on topic for our site. Questions about writing techniques are absolutely under our scope. I suggest looking at the [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction) and [technique](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technique) tags for inspiration.

However the question is currently a little broad. It would help if you could define the intended audience for the paper and give a bit of background on the techniques you have tried/looked at and what you are specifically struggling with.

Good luck and happy writing!

---

### Update based on the revision

Question is on topic and focused enough but you need to clarify exactly what the question you are asking is. E.g. *"How to write a multipage introduction for a scientific paper?"*

I suggest you go ahead and post it. We can guide you further on main site if required.

Comment: Can I revise my post and you adjust your feedback?

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky Typically revised posts should get a new question. But in this situation I suggest you just post the revised question to main site. You can continue to edit it based on the feedback you get there if it is required.